# solution for custom React Native Carousel like example image

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flatlist

I want to create slider in carousel in react native like the example image below
I want three View to be displayed on each slide And the middle slide is bigger than another and show my Text in the middle slide
Does anyone have a solution for creating this slider with FlatList?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxcpn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use https://github.com/meliorence/react-native-snap-carousel for the carousel view.

[image: carousel]

Comment: I want only the text to be displayed in the middle slide

Comment: You may reference `index` of carousel to show and hide text of each silde.